# Terraform - AWS permission boundary using IAM variables for multi account

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to create a AWS IAM permission boundary. It's essential a IAM Policy. This will be deployed to multi accounts. I don't want to hardcode all Account IDs so I like to use IAM Variables. Unfortunately, AWS does not support IAM variable for Account IDs. i.e. ${accountId}

Can someone please suggest an idea on how Terraform can deploy to multi accounts without hardcoding the Account IDs? I can use a variable, but that's still hardcoding the variable.

Here's my template:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "boundary" {
  statement {
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [
      "cloudtrail:StopLogging"
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:iam:::${accountId}:polciy/POLICY-NAME",
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current account using [aws_caller_identity](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/caller_identity). For example:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "boundary" {
  statement {
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [
      "cloudtrail:StopLogging"
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:iam:::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:policy/POLICY-NAME",
    ]
  }
}
```